# How do I configure phpMyAdmin to start with a blank sql query from the SQL tab?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Clicking on the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin takes me to a query box containing the text

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE 1
```

I have to overwrite this each time I run a query. How do I configure phpMyAdmin so that the query box is blank so that I can just paste in my SQL without having to remove the default text first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your phpMyAdmin configuration file

```
$cfg['DefaultQueryTable'] = '';
```

For help on setting up a phpMyAdmin configuration file, please see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html